# Generating cones having no surjections [in operator spaces]

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is this little toy known ?

Let $E$ be some Banach space, and let $K$ be the closed unit ball
of its dual, endowed with the weak-star topology. Also, let $j:E$ $\rightarrow$ $C(K)$
be the natural embedding. Then, if $\pi$ :$E$ $\rightarrow$ $C(K)$
is onto, one must have $\left\Vert \pi-j\right\Vert $ > 1. [Applying
this to $E=$ $\ell^{1}$, or to $E=C[0,1]$ (eventually, via Milutin)
would be interesting, I think.]

Comment: What's up with this "subjective-argumentative" tag?  I question whether it (i) applies here and (ii) would be a useful tag for any post.  It seems to me that application of this tag is, itself, rather subjective and argumentative.  

Comment: The remark looks too trivial to give much of anything.  Note that the conclusion follows if e.g. you only assume that the range $\pi$ contains the constant functions.

Comment: Maybe less trivial: it is true also when $\pi$ has a dense range.